# Alerting For Multiple Empty Selects

Tags: jquery

I am look to create an alert for both my `Dealers` select and my `QTY` select. I am able to get the alert to work by checking if either or has an empty value. But if they both have an empty value I do not want alert after alert I would rather have a combined alert saying "Hey Dummy both selects are empty".

I feel like I am getting close but advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
$("#LogItIn").click(function () {
      var dealer = $("#Dealers");
      var Quantity = $("#Qty");

        if ( dealer.val() === "" ) {
            alert("Please select a dealer.");
                if ($.browser.Chrome) {
                    dealer.click();
                } else {
                    dealer.focus();
                }
        }

        if ( Quantity.val() === "" ) {
            alert("Please select quantity.");
                if ($.browser.Chrome) {
                    Quantity.click();
                } else {
                    Quantity.focus();
                }
        }


    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vproe9bp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just added another conditional at the very beginning, this could def do with being tidied up though...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#LogItIn").click(function () {

      var dealer = $("#Dealers");
      var qty = $("#Qty");

        if(qty.val() === "" && dealer.val() === "")
            alert("Both empty dummy.")

        else if(dealer.val() === "") 
        {
            alert("Please select a dealer.")

            if ($.browser.Chrome)
                dealer.click()
            else
                dealer.focus()
        }

        else if (qty.val() === "") 
        {
            alert("Please select quantity.")

            if ($.browser.Chrome)
                qty.click();
            else
                qty.focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: wont let me accept for 10 minutes but then I will. Thank you very much

Comment: Cool no probs... im just about to update a tidier version ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you open to suggestion but you can improve your implementation in the following way. This way you can add multiple select tags without changing your js code.

```
<select name="Qty" id="Qty" class="form-control" error-message="Please select a dealer.">
                            <option value="" selected></option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select name="Dealers" id="Dealers" class="form-control" error-message="Please select quantity.">
                            <option value="" selected></option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="LogItIn"><u>L</u>OG IT IN</button>

 $("#LogItIn").click(function () {
         var alertMessage = "";
         var itemToFocus;
        $('select').each(function()
         {
            if(!$(this).val())
            {
                alertMessage += $(this).attr("error-message");
               if(itemToFocus == undefined)
                 itemToFocus = $(this);               
            }                      
        }); 

        alert(alertMessage);
        if ($.browser.Chrome)
                $(itemToFocus).click();
            else
                $(itemToFocus).focus();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vproe9bp/3/